# Editing profile in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out how to edit and update a profile from a custom html form. I have watched tutorials on how to use `UserChangeForm` to potentially inherit fields from Django's inbuilt change form and change a profile using this. But I would rather use the html page that comes with the template I am using.

This is the html file of the profilepage:

```
...
<li><a href={% url editprofile %}>Edit Profile</a></li>
...
```

the html of the template to edit the profile page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="app-instructor-profile.html" method="post" >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="photo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Avatar</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="media v-middle">
                            <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="icon-block width-100 bg-grey-100">
                                <i class="fa fa-photo text-light"></i>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-sm paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated> Add Image<i class="fa fa-upl"></i></a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder= {{ user.first_name }}>
                                <label for="first_name">First name</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="form-control-material">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder={{ user.last_name }}>
                                <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder={{ user.email }}>
                              <label for="inputEmail3">Email address</label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Change Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <label for="inputPassword3">Password</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                            <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="">
                            <label for="checkbox3">Subscribe to our Newsletter</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group margin-none">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

teachers.py (views)

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
def edit_user(request,pk):
user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
form = MentorProfileForm(instance=user)

if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MentorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            update = form.save(commit=False)
            update.user = user
            update.save()
        return HttpResponse('Confirm')
    else:
        form = MentorProfileForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'teachers:app-student-profile', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin']
        )
        return user
#edit mentor profile
class MentorProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        exclude = ['user']
```

and models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Profile of user {}".format(self.user.username)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_or_update(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Mentor.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

I would like a user signed in to click edit profile, be redirected to the html template to edit the profile page and to update their information based on changes made. When I run my code however I get this error message

> 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

**UPDATE**
Did some research on stackoverflow and made a few changes to my code

teachers.py (views)

```
#edit mentor profile
def edit_user(request,pk):
    user = request.user
    form = MentorProfileForm(initial={'first_name':user.first_name,'last_name':user.last_name,'email':user.email})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            user.email = request.POST['email']
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s'%(reverse('profile')))
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, "teachers:app-instructor-profile",context)
```

urls.py

```
path('teachers/', include(([
    path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

I am still however getting the same error message

> 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Comment: I do not fully understand where you are stuck. Are you asking how to use a ModelForm to update a model in a webpage? BTW: You have posted code for a ```TeacherSignupForm``` which is not used anywhere in the code you posted

Comment: @Chris I guess i'm a bit confused I would like to use the form  I added to the question (html of template)  to edit a user's signup info (ie firstname lastname etc)

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) about using forms in templates?

Comment: @Chris I have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is most probably caused by your `create_or_update` signal. The line

```
instance.profile.save()
```

is trying to call a `save()` on some `profile` attribute of your `User` instance. However, the `User` model you posted does not show any attribute called `profile`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that line. If I unerstand your code correctly you are trying to create an associated `Mentor`when a new user is created. For this you do not need that line an can take it out.